# What is the best way to specify boundaries on a map in an rpg? [iOS]

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit, collision

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around creating boundaries for my town.
I'm using SpriteKit right now to create an rpg, and I have made a simple town for my character to walk around on. Obviously right now he is walking through all the houses/water/fences because its just a background image.

What is the best way to specify areas that he cannot walk through? (If so, I guess this is a secondary sub question. Can anyone recommend how I should go about charting my image? Is there some tool that I can stick my image on and it will tell me the coordinates of where I click?)

Does this mean mapping the coordinates of each house and creating a boundary around it? 
Or should I creating each house/fence/body of water as an node?

Comment: How have you created the map for the town? Have you used any tool or simply coded it?

Comment: I have drawn a map in flash and exported a png file.

Answer (score 1):

Create SKSpriteNodes at the location of your houses, walls, etc.

You can make the boundaries like:

```
SKSpriteNode boundary1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor Black] size: CGSizeMake(0,0)];
boundary1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(boundary1 height,boundary1 width)];
boundary1.position = CGPointMake(boundary1 x loc, boundary1 y loc);

boundary1.categoryBitMask = boundaryCategory;
boundary1.collisionBitMask = mainPlayerCategory;
```

By setting the main character's physicsBody to collide with the main player, SpriteKit will automatically ensure that the player is only able to pass through appropriate areas.

Please ensure that the player is set to collide with boundaryCategory.

Comment: By doing this, should I limit the size of my map per scene since it could have too many nodes on screen at one time?

Comment: There is no limit to how many nodes you can have.  The limit stems from memory.  This is just a super generic way to prevent your player from walking through things.  Apply this anywhere you don't want your player to walk through.